# UI Updating using observable property in knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to update UI when changes the observable property of view model.

ViewModel is:

```
 function UserViewModel() {
        var self = this;       
        self.name = ko.observable("Test User")
    }
```

Declaring object and updating observable property on button clicks

```
 var userViewModel = {};
        $("#button").click(funtion(){
          userViewModel.name("Test");
        })
```

Apply binding on view model

```
$(funtion(){
            userViewModel = new UserViewModel();
            ko.applyBindings(userViewModel); 
})
```

and View is

```
<span data-bind="text:name"></span>
```

or

```
<span data-bind="text:name()"></span>
```

Thanks, Please suggest.

Comment: Why use jquery for the click? It seems you are overriding your `viewmodel`... first you wrote `var userViewModel = {};` then `userViewModel = new UserViewModel();` then this override your original `viewmodel` but the click handler would still reference the old `var userViewModel = {};`...

Comment: I declare variable `var userViewModel = {};` so that applybindings call once  for view model.

Comment: Thanks  @nemesv ! It provide a way to solve my problem. Good hint +1

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but I would recommend handling the click with a knockout binding, instead of using jQuery.

```
function UserViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable("Test User");
    self.update = function() {
        self.name("Test");
    };    
}

ko.applyBindings(new UserViewModel());


<span data-bind="text:name"></span>
<button data-bind="click: update">Update</button>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wsqb8pa9/)

Comment: Thanks for response, but I want to update model via JavaScript with dynamic values.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from doing that. Knockout is designed to make updating viewmodel values from JavaScript easy: that is its primary use case. If you have a specific question please ask it. I just re-used the code you posted; if this wasn't the right code, why did you use it?